# generating a hash for data larger than memory (without getting arrested)

Tags: c++, hash, murmurhash

Good afternoon Overflowers! ;)

**What I want to do:**

I'm interested in verifying transferred file integrity.

**How I approached it:**

I was considering using a hash code for this but there's one problem. The files can be extremely large so I need to be able to iteratively generate the hash. I can't load the entire file into memory.

**What I've looked at so far:**

I'm investigating [murmur3](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) and [skein](http://www.skein-hash.info/) for the hash function. I believe I understand how to make it work with skein but the version I've built fails all the known result unit tests. I'm not sure how to "chain" murmur to get a valid result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Egad! I'm calling the hash police! You'll be arrested for sure!

Comment: Well how about taking a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: I thought about CRC's but thought the hash function was superior. Thanks

Comment: A hash *is* superior - much smaller risk of collisions aka accidental undetected errors.

Comment: A hash is _not_ superior. If they appear to have a smaller risk of collisions, it's because they produce more bits than CRC-32. Compare same-width hash and CRC functions

Comment: Comparing a 32 bit CRC to a 128/256/512 bit hash isn't a valid comparison. The consensus of people who've studied it more than I is that Hash is better for detecting intentional modifications. That was actually my main concern though I didn't state it here. Thanks to everyone for the education, and to glowcoder for reporting me to the hash police. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most hash algorithms operate on fixed-size blocks of data - you can e.g. look up SHA1 or MD5 reference implementations, they use an "init/loop { update }/finalize" construct allowing you to pass as much or little data as you wish in every update.

Looking at e.g. Skein, they use the same concept in their reference implementation:

```
int  Skein_256_Init  (Skein_256_Ctxt_t *ctx, size_t hashBitLen);
int  Skein_256_Update(Skein_256_Ctxt_t *ctx, const u08b_t *msg, size_t msgByteCnt);
int  Skein_256_Final (Skein_256_Ctxt_t *ctx, u08b_t * hashVal);
```

Why do you think you need to pass the entire data as one block? Are you looking at simplified wrapper functions?

Comment: I have a version of it that compiles but I can't make it generate the outputs the author got. He provides a set of "KAT" test results for his submission to the SHA contest committee.

Comment: I was looking at murmur hash and don't see a way to use it iteratively like you can with skein. The only problem is I don't believe my version of skein is working correctly. I can't get it to produce the correct responses according to it's author's paper. I guess I will just keep trying to debug skein.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Even though the skein code doesn't get what I think should be the correct answer it is passing tests designed to see if it's a working hash.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). It's my favorite cryptographic C++ library.

And [here's](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hash_Functions#The_SHA_algorithm) how you could use it.